# Evaluating/Tuning hyper parameters of a neural network regression model

Tags: regression, cross-validation, hyperparameter, model-evaluation

I have a fairly reasonable understanding of the theory behind neural networks, regularization, and cross-validation, but I am lacking in the actual experience department.

In a nutshell, I am using a neural network regression model to make predictions of prices based off of several variables, most of them being categorical (34 categorical, 4 continuous). Using about 4000 examples. I am using scikit-learn to do this analysis.

When it comes time for me to tune my hyperparameters, the "best" score I get from using GridSearchCV doesn't necessarily give me the "best" score from scoring the Neural Network. I assume this is okay because it is doing cross-validation and the bias will be slightly off.

Am I correct in assuming I should listen to what GridSearchCV tells me are the "optimal" hyperparameter tunings?

How much should I rely on the r^2 as an evaluation of my neural network? Higher is better, but is there anything more to it than that?

Are there any graphs I can use to help me make some judgment?

Thank you all, and let me know if I am leaving out any pertinent information!

Answer (score 1):

Well, scoring the neural network as-is is not going to give you the right clues about how the neural network will perform on out-of-sample data, because it's too biased an estimation. So ideally you should perform grid search to find the best neural network, and then evaluate its results on a different data set altogether (or better, use nested cross-validation).

As far as the plotting part goes, you should use the learning curves to see if the network is overfitting (scikit has a function that does that for you); you should also plot a train-validation curve, which is useful to control how the net is learning (not sure if scikit has support for it, assuming you are using MLPClassifier).

About R^2, I used to read [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/that-damn-r-squared/) article that argues it's not that useful, but it seems the images are off. See if you can make sense of it, otherwise I'll have to find a paper I read some time ago where R^2 was criticized as well. Moral of the story, my advice is don't trust R^2 too much.

Comment: To your first point, I did split my data 75/25 for train/test sets, and I am using r^2 to score the performance on the test set. To your second point, I am using MLPRegressor, not MLPClassifier since I am doing a regression as opposed to a classification.

Comment: If I do not use R^2, can you propose an alternative metric to select one model over another?

Comment: Yeah sure, I wrote MLPClassifier but intended MLPRegressor, obviously. I think MSE would be more appropriated than R^2, but that is kind of my opinion.

Comment: First point:, you are selecting your model based on its evaluation on a single test set. It might be the case that you got "lucky" with that particular choice for a test set, and that could explain the higher performance (which would probably be not quite as high using another test set)